# Why does the total Heap Memory capacity vary in the GC logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am using a java application and while analyzing the GC logs I could see that at one point the frequency of Full GCs have increased. From the logs I was able to understand that there was a large processing inflicted on the application during this time and a large no. threads were in blocked state.

During the high frequency full GCs, the capacity of the heap as shown in the gc log has reduced.

before the issue
1978609K->1567890K(X)

during issue
1778609K->1567890K(X-400MB)

after issue
1978609K->1567890K(X)

ie. if the capacity is shown as x before the issue, during the issue the capacity has decreased by 400 MB and then once the application recovered the capacity has again increased. My question is , why does the capacity reduce?

What factors can dynamically affect the heap capacity?
max and min heap have been configured as X

The java version is 1.7.0  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
I have not modified the adaptive policy. So the default setup is present.

Let me make my question more clear. I understand that GC can occur even before the full heap memory is used. But the value in brackets in the below GC log as I understand should always remain the same showing the total available heap or heap capacity. It is this heap capacity change that worries me. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

```
[Full GC 1778609K->1567890K(total available heap), 1,5589690 secs]
```

Comment: The Heisenburg effect.  The heap size only changes when you observe it.  (So stop.)

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of *possible* explanation.  (Garbage collector implementation is complicated, and in modern JVMs you have the added complexity that there are different *kinds* of collectors that behave differently.)

However, one possible (simple) explanation is caused by object size variability.

> The garbage collection is typically triggered when your code tries to allocate a new object, and there is not enough free memory available.  If your code tries to allocate a large object, then it may trigger garbage collection *earlier* (i.e. when the heap is less full) than if it just tried to allocated small objects.

Hence the "during issue" log could simply be caused your application needing to allocate a really large object.  For example, you might have a large, long-lived `ArrayList` or `HashMap` that needed to be expanded.  Or maybe you have a request type that requires a large temporary array or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of spaces, eden, survivor and tenured.  A minor GC is triggered when the eden space, (which can change in size) fills up.  The amount used at this point can vary, but this doesn't imply the capacity or maximum memory has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like adaptive sizing where the "border" between young and old generation can move. You did not say what Java runtime you use, which version and what GC is configured. Try `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.